# android ndk - ANativeWindow_lock inconsistent?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I'm coding for android 2.3.
I wrote this program; it draws a white, 100-pixel long diagonal line from (0,0) to (99,99).

There is a bug: The code draws the screen properly only the first time it executes.
Every time after, it draws two shorter diagonal lines; a greenish-yellow line and a blue line.
Each line appears about half the correct length.
The greenish-yellow line appears to start at (0,0) but the blue one appears to start at around (200,0)

I've noticed that each time the code executes, the **ANativeWindow_Buffer.format** may be different, don't know if that's related.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Thanks for the help

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android_native_app_glue.h>

ANativeWindow_Buffer buffer;

void Out( int x, int y ) {

    uint16_t * pPixel = buffer.bits;

    /* Compute correct x,y */
    pPixel += ( x + ( y * buffer.stride ) );

    /* put a white pixel there */
    *pPixel = -1;

}


void drawscreen( struct android_app * app ) {

    unsigned u;

    for ( u = 0; u < 100; u++ ) {

        Out( u, u );

    }

}


static void android_handle_cmd( struct android_app * app, int32_t cmd ) {

    switch ( cmd ) {

        case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:

            // The window is being shown.
            if ( NULL == app->window ) {

                return;

            }

            if ( 0 > ANativeWindow_lock( app->window, &buffer, NULL ) ) {

                return;

            }

            drawscreen( app );

            ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost( app->window );
            break;

    }

}


void android_main( struct android_app * app ) {

    app_dummy();

    app->onAppCmd     = android_handle_cmd;

    for ( ;; ) {

        int events;

        int iRet;

        struct android_poll_source * source;

        iRet = ALooper_pollAll( -1, NULL, &events, (void**)&source );

        if ( NULL != source ) {

            source->process( app, source );
            continue;

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
  int32_t w = ANativeWindow_getWidth(app->window);
  int32_t h = ANativeWindow_getHeight(app->window);
  ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(app->window, w, h, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGB_565);
```

before the call to drawscreen